# Trouble selecting a single table using selenium

Tags: vba, selenium, web-scraping

I tried to scrape table data from a webpage with selenium. However, it parses all tables from that page but I need a single one. I can't find any idea as to how I can select a single table. This is what I tried with:

```
Sub table_data()
    Dim driver As New WebDriver
    Dim tabl As Object, rdata As Object, cdata As Object

    Set driver = New WebDriver
    driver.Start "Phantomjs", "https://fantasy.premierleague.com"
    driver.get "/player-list/"
    For Each tabl In driver.FindElementsByXPath("//table[@class='ism-table']")
        For Each rdata In tabl.FindElementsByXPath(".//tr")
            For Each cdata In rdata.FindElementsByXPath(".//td")
            y = y + 1
            Cells(x, y) = cdata.Text
            Next cdata
            x = x + 1
            y = 0
        Next rdata
    Next tabl
End Sub
```

I did it with XHR, though!

```
Sub TableData()
Dim xmlpage As New XMLHTTP60
Dim htmldoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim htmlas As Object, tRow As Object, tCel As Object

x = 1
With xmlpage
    .Open "GET", "https://fantasy.premierleague.com/player-list/", False
    .send
    htmldoc.body.innerHTML = .responseText
End With
Set htmlas = htmldoc.getElementsByTagName("table")(2)
For Each tRow In htmlas.Rows
    For Each tCel In tRow.Cells
        c = c + 1
        Cells(x, c) = tCel.innerText
    Next tCel
    c = 0
    x = x + 1
Next tRow
End Sub
```

Comment: Which table do you need? Cannot you get it with the index?

Comment: Thanks  PRAISER for your answer. There are eight tables out there. Any one will do. In case of indexing, I don't understand where should I put that number in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply break the `ForEach` loop once the first table's rows is do

```
Sub table_data()
    Dim driver As New WebDriver
    Dim tabl As Object, rdata As Object, cdata As Object

    Set driver = New WebDriver
    driver.Start "Phantomjs", "https://fantasy.premierleague.com"
    driver.get "/player-list/"
    For Each tabl In driver.FindElementsByXPath("//table[@class='ism-table']")
        For Each rdata In tabl.FindElementsByXPath(".//tr")
            For Each cdata In rdata.FindElementsByXPath(".//td")
            y = y + 1
            Cells(x, y) = cdata.Text
            Next cdata
            x = x + 1
            y = 0
        Next rdata
        Goto end_of_for
    Next tabl
    end_of_for:
End Sub
```

or simply only get the first element of your `FindElementsByXPath` as `driver.FindElementsByXpath(....)(0)` should return the first element.

**--(EDIT)**

According to [this docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474) you should be able to get the right value by `Items` so it'll be `driver.FindElementsByXpath(....).Item(4)`.

Comment: Thanks PRAISER for your answer. This method is something new to me. It does parse the first table. However, If i wanted to parse the fourth table what could I change in the method you applied above? FYI, indexing shows error. If i could apply your second method It would be awesome!!

Comment: You are the gem of a guy brother. Hats off. You made my day. Btw, the line should be [Set tabl = driver.FindElementsByXPath("//table[@class='ism-table']").Item(1)]

Comment: One last thing to urge: If i try you first method, Is it possible to select any specific table? Curious to know. Thanks for everything.

Comment: Yes, just put the `Goto` in the beginning of loop before the next `ForEach` and add a conditional to make sure the index is the right one. But you need to keep track of indexes by declaring it out of the first loop.

Comment: Thanks a trillion for everything. Your indexing method (using Item property) works for regular vba as well. I wish i could hit the upvote button several times.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you may do that just via XHR and Split, no need to use Selenium. Take a look at the below code:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Scrape_premierleague_com()

    Dim sResponse, j, i, aRows, aCells

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://fantasy.premierleague.com/player-list/", False
        .Send
        sResponse = .responseText
    End With
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells.Delete
    sResponse = Split(Split(sResponse, "<tbody>")(1), "</tbody>", 2)(0) ' 1 - number of the table
    aRows = Split(sResponse, "<tr>")
    For j = 1 To UBound(aRows)
        aCells = Split(aRows(j), "<td>")
        For i = 1 To UBound(aCells)
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(j, i).Value = Split(aCells(i), "</td>", 2)(0)
        Next
    Next
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Columns.AutoFit

End Sub
```

Here is the output for me:

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks sir omegastripes, for your sweet and nice solution. Actually, I did with XHR in the first place. I needed to know how to parse table in case it is encrypted in javascript and i never tried to parse a table using selenium until now. The above site was a specimen. However, your style is something different and concise. Thanks.